# How to convert a string to a double with 6-digit precision in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, string-conversion

I want to know how to convert a string like `"1234.123456"` to `double` or `float`.
I need at least 3 digits precision (i.e. 3 digits after the decimal point, regardless of the number of digits before the point).

Comment: `double use to scale it in total 6 digits,` O_o

Comment: See e.g. [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) or [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: my compiler tells me that 
  double d=1234.123456  
  cout<<d<<endl;
output:1234.12

Comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << d << std::endl` outputs `1234.1235`. So no you can't use the output to know the precision.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK take a look here - [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: ok, gotcha! Sorry, didnt go thru it earlier....

Comment: @Fiktik `std::setprecision` has no impact on input.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK That's because the default output precision is 6.  It has nothing to do with the precision of a `double`.

Comment: _"since `double` uses 6 digits in total"_ -- eh? A double has about 15 significant decimal digits

Comment: So do you want to convert a string to a double OR print formatted a double?

Comment: @JamesKanze I never said anything about input. It was merely a reaction to OP's comment.

Answer (score 6):

The exact value 1234.123456 isn't representable in any of the usual
machine floating point formats.  All you can do is choose how much
accuracy you need, and use it.  (On most modern machines, `double` has
16 digits precision.  But that still doesn't mean that all 16 digit
values are exactly representable.)

As for the conversion, just do what you would do to convert any type:

```
std::istringstream s( "1234.123456" );
double d;
s >> d;
```

And read
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.  It will
explain the basic minimum you need to know in order to safely use
machine floating point.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    double dnum = atof( "1234.123456" ) ;

    printf ( "%f\n" , dnum ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```